# JMockit - Mock 2nd time and ignore first time

Tags: java, methods, jmockit

I am new to JMockit and would like to mock a java method when its running 2nd time and ignore first time when it's been called.

Example i want to mock the runningMethod() below when it's returning a string with "second time" and perform some other operations.

```
@Mock publicMethod() 
{
//do something if calling runningMethod() 2nd time.
}


int count = 1;
public String runningMethod()

{

if (count == 1) return "first time";

if (count == 2) return "second time";

i++;

return "some answers";
}
```

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer: http://www.baeldung.com/jmockit-expectations

but here is the relevant code from that post:

```
public interface ExpectationsCollaborator{
    String methodReturnsString();
    int methodReturnsInt();
}

@Test
public void testResultAndReturns(@Mocked Foo mock){
    new StrictExpectations() {{
        mock.methodReturnsString();
        result = "foo";
        result = new Exception();
        result = "bar";
        mock.methodReturnsInt(); result = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        mock.methodReturnsString(); returns("foo", "bar");
        mock.methodReturnsInt(); result = 1;
    }};

    assertEquals("Should return foo", "foo", mock.methodReturnsString());
    try {
        mock.methodReturnsString();
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    assertEquals("Should return bar", "bar", mock.methodReturnsString());
    assertEquals("Should return 1", 1, mock.methodReturnsInt());
    assertEquals("Should return 2", 2, mock.methodReturnsInt());
    assertEquals("Should return 3", 3, mock.methodReturnsInt());
    assertEquals("Should return foo", "foo", mock.methodReturnsString());
    assertEquals("Should return bar", "bar", mock.methodReturnsString());
    assertEquals("Should return 1", 1, mock.methodReturnsInt());
}
```